# HTTP Header on specific page is application instead of text

Tags: headers, http

Problem: clicking on (WP site that I developed) webejeeping.com/vehicles/ causes the generated php file to be downloaded instead of being rendered in the browser. MIME Type returns as "application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8" instead of "text/html; charset-UTF-8". This is apparently the only page on this site that exhibits this behavior.

The problem is not happening all of the time (according to another user) although I consistently experience it.

Other info: This site makes heavy use of Pods (pods.io) and the problem page is the "index" page for the main content type. Other pages work as expected. The site is hosted on a Hostgator reseller account for what that's worth.

What could be the problem? Could this be a WP issue or an issue with the host maybe?

Comment: There really isn't enough information to go on here, but did you try renaming that one page to see if that makes any difference?

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I haven't tried renaming the page.  The "Vehicles" menu item and sub-menu is generated by a Pods loop.  I have some conditional statements in there that depend on the page being named "vehicles".  I'd be glad to provide additional info that would help with troubleshooting.  I usually don't work this low in the tech stack so I'm not sure what would be helpful.